# change var. names to their labels SAS

Tags: sas

How to change the variables names (`col1,col2,....`) to there labels ??

I used proc `glmmod` to get dummy matrix for all categorical variables into other dataset. But I can't get the original names of variables.

Comment: I have 60 variables, so it is too hard to do it one by one

Comment: one can see this question as the inverse of this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27723334/set-the-labels-of-a-sas-dataset-equal-to-their-variable-name

Comment: GLMMOD is returning the label and not the varname?  If that's the case then why not just remove the label (as in the linked question) before using GLMMOD?  Or is GLMMOD creating variables with generic names and the original names as labels?  Example code and desired input/output would be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's code from SAS to do just that! ([Reference](http://support.sas.com/kb/24/720.html))

```
/* Sample data set with variables containing labels */
data t1;  
   label x='this_x' y='that_y';
   do x=1,2;
      do y=3,4;
         z=100;
         output;
      end;
   end;
run;

/* Functions such as OPEN, ATTRN, VARNAME, and VARLABEL are used to  retrieve variable names and  */
/* labels.  Macro variables are then created to hold the variable names and variable labels.     */
/* We then loop through the number of variables (&num) in the data set passed to the macro (t1). */
/* If a variable contains a label, then the RENAME statement in PROC DATASETS is generated to    */ 
/* contain the proper renaming.                                                                  */
                                                                                                           
%macro chge(dsn);                                                                                                                 
   %let dsid=%sysfunc(open(&dsn));                                                                                                        
   %let num=%sysfunc(attrn(&dsid,nvars));                                                                                                 
   %do i= 1 %to  #                                                                                                                    
      %let var&i=%sysfunc(varname(&dsid,&i));                                                                                             
      %let lab&i=%sysfunc(varlabel(&dsid,&i));                                                                                            
      %if &&lab&i = %then %let lab&i=&&var&i;                                                                                            
    %end;                                                                                                                                 
   %let rc=%sysfunc(close(&dsid));                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                    
   proc datasets;                                                                                                                          
     modify &dsn;                                                                                                                           
          rename                                                                                                                                 
      %do j = 1 %to  #                                                                                                                  
         %if &&var&j ne &&lab&j %then   %do;                                                                                                   
          &&var&j=&&lab&j                                                                                                                    
       %end;                                                                                                                               
    %end;;                                                                                                                               
 quit;                                                                                                                                   
 run;                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                    
%mend chge;  

%chge(t1)

proc contents;                                                                                                                          
run;
```